# django-cms not loading custom menus

Tags: django-cms

I have already followed once the instructions at http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html# in order to customize my menu, and everything worked smoothly.

Now I am trying to replicate the same thing in a new project: I created `cms_menus.py` in the app directory (the same where `settings.py` is stored) but django-cms just ignores it: it does not even get compiled.

My django and django-cms versions are as follows:

- Django==1.11.15
- django-cms==3.5.2

Any clues or suggestions on how to debug the issue?

UPDATE:
Here is my project tree, I have removed non pertinent entries

```
.
├── cms
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── activate
│   │   ├── activate.csh
│   │   ├── activate.fish
│   │   ├── activate_this.py
│   │   ├── django-admin
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── wheel
│   ├── include
│   ├── lib
│   ├── local
│   └── pip-selfcheck.json
├── h2h
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── h2h
│   │   ├── cms_menus.py
│   │   ├── cms_plugins.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── settings.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   ├── urls.pyc
│   │   ├── views.py
│   │   ├── views.pyc
│   │   ├── wsgi.py
│   │   └── wsgi.pyc
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
└── requirements_new.txt
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't even get compiled, what do you mean? Have you confirmed that there isn't the menu choice in the advanced settings menus option for a page? What other things does the app do that your menu belongs to? Do those other parts work?

Comment: By "the file doesn't get compiled", I mean that there is no .pyc file.
The standard features for menus work, but not the custom menu. I also tried adding a cms_plugins.py and that doesn't compile either.

Comment: Can you post your folder structure? I find it odd that cms_menus is in the same directory as settings.py

Comment: I've added the tree to the original post. As you can see other custom files, such as urls.py and views.py get compiled properly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I feel really stupid. Notice to self: always check INSTALLED_APPS before posting questions on StackOverflow. I.e. the app name was missing from the list.